# How to send a Data Message without notification to ios app?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) with ios app. I'm now trying to get a `data message without notification` using following method

```
application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:)
```

Can I send a data message using http://pushtry.com/? I have tried sending a data message from this site but nothing happens, while notification are working fine.

JSON for data message

```
{
  "message":{
    "token":"mytoken comes here",
    "data":{
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "body" : "great match!",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any other site to test the `data message without notification`?

Comment: you can do this on firebase console.

Answer (score 1):

You can send a silent notification with FCM by adding `content_available` as `true` to your payload.

```
{
  "message": {
    "token": "mytoken comes here",
    "content_available": true,
    "priority": "high",
    "data": {
      "Nick": "Mario",
      "body": "great match!",
      "Room": "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Response: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Answer (score 0):

> This worked for us, you can use this to get data in the foreground & background of your application. This sends it silently and the user does not see it but you can programmatically react to this in your application.

```
{
  "to": "{{fcm-token-here}}",
  "content_available": true,
  "data": {
    "story_id": "story_12345"
  }
}
```

Comment: This currently works for both Android and iOS.